# Jasper CSV Export Adding Extra Comma On The Last Row

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using CSV Exporter and getting these rows. As you can see there is an extra comma in the bottom row.

361,,"$ 20,008,000",,,"$ 101,050.36",,Iowa,,"$ 55,424",,$ 279.92,,51,48,,50

336,,"$ 20,111,000",,,"$ 79,444.16",,Massachusetts,,"$ 59,854",,$ 236.44,,51,48,,50

340,,"$ 21,988,000",,,"$ 71,521.48",,Minnesota,,"$ 64,671",,$ 210.36,,50,48,,49

346,,"$ 22,566,000",,,"$ 84,231.26",,Nevada,,"$ 65,220",,$ 243.44,,51,47,,49

347,,"$ 30,167,000",,,"$ 91,036.54",,North Carolina,,"$ 86,937",,$ 262.35,,50,49,,50

1,,"$ 500,000",,,"$ 2,500.00",,Pennsylvania,,"$ 500,000",,"$ 2,500.00",,49,0,,49

5,,"$ 980,000",,,"$ 4,345.32",,Tennessee,,"$ 196,000",,$ 869.06,,47,65,,58

352,,"$ 25,236,000",,,"$ 86,870.26",,Texas,,"$ 71,693",,$ 246.79,,49,48,,49

354,,"$ 27,026,000",,,"$ 97,053.16",,Virginia,,"$ 76,345",,$ 274.16,,49,47,,48

15250,,,"$ 1,121,193,000",,,"$ 4,521,167.29",,"$ 73,521",,$ 296.47,,,50,49,50,

The jrxml for the bottom row is as follows. Can someone please tell me what needs to be adjusted here? Thanking you

```
<group name="mygroup">
    <groupFooter>
    <band height="123">
                    <rectangle>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1" y="1" width="558" height="23" backcolor="#00CC99" />
                    </rectangle>

                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="28" width="553" height="86" />
                            <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="7" isBold="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Disclosure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>

                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="$ #,##0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="49" y="2" width="80" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumFaceAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>

                            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="2" width="48" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumCounts}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="$ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="385" y="2" width="80" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{avgPremium}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="$ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="130" y="2" width="85" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{sumPremium}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="$ #,##0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="304" y="2" width="80" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{avgFaceAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="533" y="2" width="25" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Avg_Tage}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="507" y="2" width="26" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Avg_Fage}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="478" y="2" width="28" height="14" forecolor="#000000" />
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Avg_Mage}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>

    </band>
    </groupFooter>
    </group>
```

Comment: You should remove this comma or add comma for other lines

Comment: So just to be clear, you export an csv file from the report and then an additional comma comes up? Can we see the last row from the report in a picture?

Comment: What is the pageWidth of your report?